# When does $\hom(A,-)$ have trivial kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

If $R$ is a commutative ring, is there a special name for those $R$-modules $A$ with the following property?

> $\forall R$-modules $M$: $~\hom(A,M) = 0 \Rightarrow M = 0$

Notice that every every (locally) free $R$-module of rank $\neq 0$ has this property. Probably there are more? What happens if we additionally assume that $A$ is faithfully flat?

Comment: If $A$ is projective and satisfies your condition then it is a strong generator (in the sense that $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$ is conservative / faithfully exact): cf [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/271373/5191).

Comment: Yes, sure. In my situation $A$ is almost never projective (again I am interested in quasi-coherent sheaves).